# How can I enable input-style scrolling without scrollbars on a div?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a link that I allow users to copy to a clipboard.

```
<div class="col-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" 
       value="http://www.[].com/thisisareallylongurlthatwilldefinitelyrequiresomexaxisscrolling">
</div>
```

When the input value is longer than the input, the default browser behaviour is to allow x-axis scroll with no scrollbars if the user clicks and selects text to the right:

[image]

I want this link to also be clickable as an `<a href=>` but to retain the style of the input. The easiest approach I thought of is simply to style a div with `form-control` and apply `overflow-x: hidden;` however this means the text does not scroll with the same behaviour as if it was in an `input`:

[image]

```
<div class="col-3">
    <div class="form-control"> 
      <a href="http://www.[].com/thisisareallylongurlthatwilldefinitelyrequiresomexaxisscrolling">
      http://www.[].com/thisisareallylongurlthatwilldefinitelyrequiresomexaxisscrolling</a>
</div>
```

**How can I enable scrolling without scrollbars on a div?**

Answer (score 1):

Use `white-space: nowrap;` and `hidden` propertry on `form-control-scrollable` class and child element position should be `absolute` with `overflow-x: auto;` like below in my style code.
*`Trick:` I have increased child(anchor tag) height 100% + `28px` for hiding bottom scrollbar.*

```css
.form-control-scrollable{
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.form-control-scrollable a{
  position: absolute;
  top: 6px;
  width: calc(100% - 28px);
  height: calc(100% + 28px); /*28px increase height for hide bottom scrollbar for 28px */
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container my-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6">
      <div class="form-control form-control-scrollable"> 
        <a href="http://www.[].com/thisisareallylongurlthatwilldefinitelyrequiresomexaxisscrolling">
          http://www.[].com/thisisareallylongurlthatwilldefinitelyrequiresomexaxisscrolling
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```css
a {
    width: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow-x: auto;
 }
 a::-webkit-scrollbar { 
  display: none; 
 }
```

```html
<a href="http://www.sdkjnsjk.com/thisisareallylongurlthatwilldefinitelyrequiresomexaxisscrolling">
          http://www.kdsjnjdsk.com/thisisareallylongurlthatwilldefinitelyrequiresomexaxisscrolling</a>
```